# Remove CR LF from text file in c#

Tags: c#, regex, newline, str-replace

I have a text file containing the following lines for example:

[image: example text file]

I want to remove the CR LF only when the previous line contains a CR at the end. Via regex I can remove oall characters, but I can't build the condition to check the previous line.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the whitespace only line that directly follows the line ending with CR? Try `(\r)\h*\r\n` and replace with `$1`

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please edit your question to place the text into the question, not an image.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I believe it is the case where  an image is better than text. Well, at least it is clear what kind of input OP has.

Comment: This "(\r)\h*\r\n" works in Notepad++, but when I use it in VS with the following code: strFile = Regex.Replace(strFile, @"(\r)\h*\r\n", "$1"); it throws an exception :(

Comment: @PatrickGrebe In C#, you just need to replace `\h` with `[\p{Zs}\t]` or `[\s-[\r\n]]`, see my answer below.

Comment: Aren't you gonna give any feedback on the answers you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the following code to archive this:

```
            String strFile = File.ReadAllText(@file, Encoding.Default);

            Regex re = new Regex("\r(?= *\r)");

            strFile = re.Replace(strFile, "");

            File.WriteAllText(@file + ".tmp", strFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace

```
\r(?= *\r)
```

with nothing.

It simply matches `CR`'s followed by `CR`'s (optionally preceded by space). The actual match is **only** the first `CR` and the rest is done by a look-ahead, so replacing only replaces the `CR` that's missing it's `LF`.

It's a slight variation of what you're asking for, because instead of removing the `CRLF`, it removes the single `CR`'s, which will make a more uniform file with all `CRLF` endings, instead of a mix of single `CR` and `CRLF` *end of lines*.

I.e.

```
Regex   re = new Regex("\r(?= *\r)");
string  sResult = re.Replace( sInput, "").ToString() );
```

[See it here at ideone](https://ideone.com/utUJhj).

**Edit**

Thinking of it, my solution will leave spaces from the beginning of a line following a `CR`-only line, at the end of it. The solution you describe will leave'm in the beginning of the next. I'm guessing the preferred would be to remove them. For this, change the RE to

```
\r *(?=\r)
```

making it **match** the spaces as well, making the replace remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(\r)[\p{Zs}\t]*\r\n
```

and replace with `$1`.

**Details**

- `(\r)` - Group 1: a CR
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*` - followed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\r\n` - and a CRLF.

Replacement is the CR captured into Group 1. See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/dlzUfn):

```
var s = "     Line 1\r     \r\n     Line 2\r\n     \r\n     more text";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"(\r)[\p{Zs}\t]*\r\n", "$1")
        .Replace("\r", "<CR>").Replace("\n", "<LF>"));
// =>      Line 1<CR>     Line 2<CR><LF>     <CR><LF>     more text
```